# Data feed for 10 year government bond yields

Tags: excel, bond-yields

I am trying to access a data feed for 10 year sovereign bond yields for countries, say the G20. I have tried world bank and IMF data api sources but to no avail.

The data feed is used to update an excel spreadsheet in order to calculate real yields.

Many Thanks,
Ivan

Answer (score 1):

I think that a combination of [Quandl](http://www.quandl.com/) and the [St. Louis Federal Reserve's database (FRED)](http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/categories/32264) should have what you're looking for.  FRED also has an [excel add-in](http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred-addin/) that would take care of getting the feeds into excel format for you.  Quandl also has an [excel add-in](http://www.quandl.com/help/packages/excel-add-in) and API resources for other languages too including Python, R, Matlab, Stata, Julia, Java, .NET, C/C++ and many more.

Comment: I often look for data and post questions. Then I get answers of the form: go to yahoo, google, quandl. This is no answer. Everybody who can do a simple internet search knows these pages. The problem in my mind is to find the right data on these pages as there are no good search tools and/or descriptions.